# Vim 7.3 with Lua: How do I use it?

Tags: vim

The latest Vim release is awesome!

I compiled it with `--enable-luainterp=yes` and it does have the Lua feature:

```
% gvim --version | egrep '\+lua'
+linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap +lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname
```

But how do I actually use it? Up until now, I was always using Vim script for my files, but how do I let it interpret Lua? And what are the bindings that I can use from inside Lua?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean vim 7.3?

Comment: Of course, silly me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So Vim 7.3 is new enough that there isn't much information about the Lua integration. However, vim has had similar support for python, ruby, perl, and tcl. So:

[Simple tutorial for python](http://tmske.blogspot.com/2007/05/python-scripting-in-vim-1.html)

[Another python guide](http://orestis.gr/blog/2008/08/10/scripting-vim-with-python/)

As well as example tutorials for the other languages, you should definitely read the vim help for Lua, do

```
 :h lua
```

to see comprehensive help and some examples. Have fun!

Comment: Yup, there's not much info about Lua scripting out there, but I can transfer from the Python guides.